# How do I create facebook style tagging friends in a textbox

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I would like to use a facebook style friend tagger on an application that is used to create blog posts. If a user enters @ sign and then starts entering a friend's name (from a user table) then the application will lookup and then user will select the name from a list. Upon selection of the name it will send an email mentioning that you have been tagged in the blog post xyz etc. After entensive googling i found similar script at http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/tag-friends-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html. However i was wondering if there more examples? or jquery extensions for this?

Comment: See JQ plugin [Select 2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Answer (score 0):

This would not take much time to research to code yourself. Use javascript / jQuery to detect the @ symbol and fire off an ajax function to find matching users in that persons friend's list. Maybe generate an xml / json file for each user's friends so you can access them quicker that way without extra queries to the DB. Then display the usernames in a simple CSS div for them to select from. When they select a name have it replace everything after the @ symbol with the selected name. Then shoot off another ajax function to trigger and log a message for that user to see when they log in next.

I know we are all at different levels here, but if you are familiar with php, javascript / jquery and ajax calls, you should be able to smash a few coffees and get this done in a few hours. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a jQuery plugin for this. Check the demo here:

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Read documentation of plugin for more info. In short:

- You need to use this plugin on client side.
- Generate JSON in following format on server and pass url of the script file to this plugin

  [
      {"id":"856","name":"House"},
      {"id":"1035","name":"Desperate Housewives"},
      ...
  ]
- Bind onAdd event listener to this plugin and send ajax request to some server side script to send the email.